# Installing pcraster on Windows 10 with Miniconda3 error message

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-3, installation

I am trying (and failing) to install pcraster. I am a rank beginner in all things coding (I haven't touched code since Basic was a hot new thing). I am on Windows 10 and using QGIS 3.24.1 and just reinstalled and updated Visual Studio 2019, then restarted my system. I am following Hans van der  Kwast's video on installing pcraster here (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6uSvW6PUiMA&list=WL&index=102&t=177s). When he says to input:

from pcraster import *

I get this error message:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\12045\miniconda3\envs\pcrasterqgis\lib\site-packages\pcraster\__init__.py", line 21, in <module>
    from ._pcraster import *
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _pcraster: The specified procedure could not be found.
> 
>

>During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

>Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\12045\miniconda3\envs\pcrasterqgis\lib\site-packages\pcraster\__init__.py", line 63, in <module>
    raise ImportError(msg)
ImportError: The 'Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2017' is required to run PCRaster, available at:
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2977003/the-latest-supported-visual-c-downloads
DLL load failed while importing _pcraster: The specified procedure could not be found.
In case you cannot solve the issue please consult the PCRaster mailing list at:
https://lists.geo.uu.nl/mailman/listinfo/pcraster-info
```

When I go to \pcraster_*init*_.py there is a message that says:

```
On Windows prepend the path to our dlls to the PATH environment variable.
 Otherwise our dlls won't be found when our Python extensions are loaded
 by Python.

 if sys.platform == "win32":
    path_ = os.environ["PATH"]
    pcraster_installation_root = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(
        os.path.dirname(__file__), "..", ".."))
    pcraster_dll_pathname = os.path.join(pcraster_installation_root, "lib")
    if os.path.exists(pcraster_dll_pathname):
        os.environ["PATH"] = pcraster_dll_pathname + os.pathsep + path_
```

I don't know how to prepend a path. If I understand correctly, in init.py where it says path_ = os.environ["PATH"] is where to prepend, but when I try that I get this error message:

```
path_ = os.environ[C:\Users\12045\miniconda3\envs\pcrasterqgis\DLLs]
                                                                       ^
SyntaxError: unexpected character after line continuation character.
```

The syntax error points at the final ]. I am at a complete loss here. What should I do?

Edited to add: Also this link: https://lists.geo.uu.nl/mailman/listinfo/pcraster-info
is broken, so I can't ask there.

Comment: You don't need to mess with the path. The comment is telling what __init__.py is doing, not what you need to do.  The error message tells you exactly what the problem is, you need to install the 'Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2017'  available at: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2977003/the-latest-supported-visual-c-downloads

Comment: Hi user2856, and thanks for the response. I have installed the Visual Studio C++ Redistributable for 2017. I did that prior to reinstalling pcraster.

Comment: Which one x86 or x64?

Answer (score 1):

I followed another video (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2pEr5RoGAXc&list=PLeuKJkIxCDj2xbV45C45wz3N89FvmTuSu&index=2) on installing PCRaster from the OSGeo4W installer and that worked a treat.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).